How can I make audio playable with other music?
When I start a music program to play a song, I want the Sounds class to play the audio without interrupting the song I am playing.
class Sounds {

  final player = AudioPlayer();

  pressSound() async {
     try {
      if (player.playing) {
        await player.dispose();
      }
      await player.setAsset('assets/music/sounds/press.wav');

      await player.play();
      await player.dispose(); 
    } catch (e) {
      LogUtil.init(
          title: 'Playing Audio Error: pressSound', isDebug: true, limitLength: 90000);
      LogUtil.v(e);
    }
  }
}

I tried to use the audio_session library with the following code, but it doesn't work.
import 'package:audio_session/audio_session.dart';


class Sounds {

  final player = AudioPlayer();

  pressSound() async {
    try {
      final session = await AudioSession.instance;
      await session.configure(AudioSessionConfiguration.speech());
      if (player.playing) {
        await player.dispose();
      }
      await player.setAsset('assets/music/sounds/press.wav');

      await player.play();
      await player.dispose();
    } catch (e) {
      LogUtil.init(
          title: '播放音频报错：pressSound', isDebug: true, limitLength: 90000);
      LogUtil.v(e);
    }
  }
}

